# How does this coin change algorithm work?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is a list of coin denominations ordered from high to low.

```
coinage = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1]
```

and the amount of money is **445**. The output of this function is

```
[(2, 200), (2, 20), (1, 5)]
```

I'm really confused about the algorithm. How does it work?

Comment: Can you include an example of your attempt at solving the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this. Since `coinage` list is already sorted in reverse, things become easy. You just need to iterate through the list and perform the logic:

```
coinage = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1]
money = 445

sum, lst = 0, []
for x in coinage:
    if x <= money:
        lst.append((money // x, x))
        sum = (money // x) * x
        money -= sum

print(lst)
# [(2, 200), (2, 20), (1, 5)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!   I was stuck on the logical part. Much appreciated